# Origin of Валюта

Tags: этимология, история-языка

I am curios about Валюта meaning currency. What is the origin of the word? Does it come from greek or latin or somewhere else?

Comment: Vassmer to the rescue: http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/main.cgi?flags=wygtmnl

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev : Wow thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wikipedia says:
Слово «валюта» происходит от итал. valuta («стоимость, монета, валюта»), связано с итал. valere («иметь вес, стоить»), которое происходит от лат. valere («быть сильным, иметь возможность, стоить»)

The word "валюта" comes from Italian. valuta ("cost, coin, currency"), is connected with ital. valere ("have weight, cost"), which comes from the lat. valere ("to be strong, to be able, to be worth»)

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B0

Comment: ...which is related to English "value".

Answer (score 2):

It's borrowed from Italian, so obviously it's coming from Latin. It's the exact same word as Italian 'valuta'.